# How to style the hover on a button?

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="navigationBar"><a href=""><input type="Submit" value="Home" class="navButton"/></a>
                    <a href=""><input type="Submit" value="Users" class="navButton"/></a>
                    <a href=""><input type="Submit" value="Administrator's Tools" class="navButton"/></a>
                    <a href=""><input type="Submit" value="Search" class="navButton"/></a>
```

The style of the button:

```
#wrapper #navigationBar a .navButton { /* Navigation Bar Buttons */
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 180px;
    height: 55px;
    font-family: Gisha;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    outline: none;

}
```

I am trying to just give it a simple hover color:

```
#navButton:hover{
background-color: grey;
color: white;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are trying to give hover style for id instead of class. try to give line a.navButton:hover

Comment: sry. you are trying to give hover style for id instead of class. try to give * like a.navButton:hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had your css by `using #navButton:hover`.

You should use a class `.navButton:hover`

Here is the Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebj2z/)

**Note :**

If you are using `#navButton:hover` call it using id, else if you are using `.navButton:hover` you should call it using class.

Comment: For some reason it still isn't working. I think it may be because of the style of the div?

Comment: Yes you might have given some other styles in any of your div. You shall remove it to make it work.

Comment: Thanks if my answer is helpful for you. Kindly make it as answered :)

Answer (score 2):

You have used hash instead of a period/fullstop

```
#navButton:hover
```

should be

```
.navButton:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
.navButton:hover{
   background-color: grey;
   color: white;
}
```